# Как присвоить переменной-результат вызова функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция

```
var rund = function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Ее например можно вызвать так:

```
alert(rand(10,20));
```

Но мне нужно следующее

```
var srotate = "rotate(" + Результат вызова функции rand + "deg)";
$(".hour").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
```

Как это сделать?!

Comment: @DreamChild а может лучше просто rand() ставить? Зачем создавать лишнюю переменную?

Comment: @intro94 разщмеется лучше. Однако пример был написан на основе кода, приведенного в вопросе

Comment: @DreamChild тоже вариант. :)

Comment: Ну и вопросы пошли :рукалицо:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
var srotate = "rotate(" + rand(10,20) + "deg)";
```

Как ещё один вариант, можно использовать предложение DreamChild-а, решил добавить такой вариант. :)

Answer (score 5):

эмм..а просто присваивание типа

```
var val = rand(10,20)
var srotate = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";
```

уже не в моде?

Comment: Да все в моде. Я так и делал. Но код не работает. И сейчас все два варианта попробовал. Результат тот же. ReferenceError: rand is not defined
var val = rand(10,20);

Comment: @HoPkInS тогда показывайте код,что и как в делаете.  Видимо вы что-то  упускаете в том коде, что у вас за кулисами. В предложенных здесь вариантах ошибкам, кроме синтаксических, взяться неоткуда - все более чем элементарно

Answer (score 0):

Нету никаких "занавесов" нет.вставил такой код и все заработало.

```
    function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var val = rand(0,180);
var srotate = "rotate(" + val + "deg)";

 $(".hour").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
```

Comment: так а в чем разница? Выглядит точно так же, как и то, что вам предлагали в ответах и комментариях

Comment: @DreamChild. В том то и дело. Я же сказал, что я делал так же, но у меня не работало. Поэтому и спросил. Думал может я в чем то ошибаюсь. А разница вот в чем. Было var rund = function rand(min, max).Стало сами видите как.